# Selecting all records from one year ago till now

Tags: mysql

I have a table filled with a lot of rows and I need to select all the rows that are less than a year old till now.

The table (called `orders`) has a `DateTime` column named `order_date`, that's the field that determines when the order was placed.

**How can I select all the records that have an `order_date` between now and a full year ago?**

Answer (score 201, accepted):

```
select * 
from orders 
where order_date >= DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 1 YEAR);
```

Comment: I think curdate() also can be used inplace of NOW()

Comment: @Dotnet , hi Dotdot , Do you know order_date is of what Datatype?? It can also be DATE TIME Field so , Why take risk ? You wont have to modify code though you change its datatype to DATE TIME . Getting ?

Answer (score 12):

```
SELECT * FROM order WHERE order_date >= curdate() - interval 1 year;
```

Answer (score 1):

To first of month a year ago

```
SELECT DATE_SUB(DATE_FORMAT(CURRENT_DATE,'%Y-%m-01'),INTERVAL 1 YEAR);
```

Answer (score -5):

I hope it helps you:

```
select * 
from table 
where (order_date BETWEEN '2/15/2011 3:36:18 PM' AND '2/17/2011 9:00:00 PM')
```

Comment: this will work only for particular date but how will you check for the change in day or year each and every time you can not change the date right